# Electron cannot draw full resolution rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

Somehow i cannot manage to draw rectangle on full screen resolution, there are always 5px from left and top, and if i try to move cursor on those bounds, rectangle draw stops, because cusror changes to default, which mean i'm on some invisible object, which i suspect is window border or something.

[image: Black lines shows the margin]

Image shows that the red frame i draw cannot cover window bounds, i marked them with black lines on top and left corners.

https://gyazo.com/d1af91eda39c227873f75ce993a3e2fe theres a quick gif of what i try to achieve.

**Code from the main.js file**

```
function createWindow () {
 const electronScreen = electron.screen

//const {width, height} = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize
const {width, height} = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().bounds

const size = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().size
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  x: 0,
   y: 0,
   width,
   height,
   //width: size.width,
   //height: size.height,
   frame: false,
   show: true,
   transparent: true,
   resizable: false,
   fullscreen: true,
   titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
   //'always-on-top': true,
   alwaysOnTop: true,
   skipTaskbar: true,
   kiosk: true,
   disableAutoHideCursor: true,
   enableLargerThanScreen: true,
   useContentSize: true,
  })  
 ...
 }
```

**Content of index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello World!</title>
<style>
html, body {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  //background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  //background-color: rgba(0, 28, 42, 0.1);
  //background: rgba(0, 28, 42, 0.1);
  //color: rgba(0, 28, 42, 0.1);
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0px;
  cursor: url(cursor.png), auto;
}

#canvasScreenshot {
width:100%;
height:100%;
//border: 10px solid transparent;
}
.rectangle {
border: 2px solid #FF0000;
position: absolute;
//background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
//background-color: #fff;
//opacity: .1;
}



</style>
</head>
<body style="" >
<div id="canvasScreenshot"></div> 
<script>
  require('./renderer.js')

  window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let {remote} = require('electron');
    remote.getGlobal("QuitApplication")();
  }, false)

    document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.which === 123) {
            require('remote').getCurrentWindow().toggleDevTools();
        } else if (e.which === 116) {
            location.reload();
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Content of renderer.js where i took screenshot and draw rect**

```
const electron = require('electron')
const electronScreen = electron.screen

const desktopCapturer = electron.desktopCapturer

const shell = electron.shell

const fs = require('fs')
const os = require('os')
const path = require('path')

initDraw(document.getElementById('canvasScreenshot'));

function initDraw(canvas) {

  var DrawDone = 0;
  var DrawStarted = 0;

    function setMousePosition(e) {
        var ev = e || window.event; //Moz || IE
        if (ev.pageX) { //Moz
            mouse.x = ev.pageX + window.pageXOffset;
            mouse.y = ev.pageY + window.pageYOffset;
        } else if (ev.clientX) { //IE
            mouse.x = ev.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            mouse.y = ev.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        }
    };

    var mouse = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        startX: 0,
        startY: 0
    };
    var element = null;

    canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
        setMousePosition(e);
        if (element !== null) {
            element.style.width = Math.abs(mouse.x - mouse.startX) + 'px';
            element.style.height = Math.abs(mouse.y - mouse.startY) + 'px';
            element.style.left = (mouse.x - mouse.startX < 0) ? mouse.x + 'px' : mouse.startX + 'px';
            element.style.top = (mouse.y - mouse.startY < 0) ? mouse.y + 'px' : mouse.startY + 'px';
        }
    }

    document.body.oncontextmenu=function(event) {
         console.log(" Right click! ");
     };

    canvas.onclick = function (e) {
      console.log(e);
        if (element !== null) {
          console.log(element);

          var ssWidth = element.style.width;
          var ssHeight = element.style.height;
          var ssLeft = element.style.left;
          var ssTop = element.style.top;

          var RectanglePosition = {
            width: parseInt(ssWidth.replace("px","")),
            height: parseInt(ssHeight.replace("px","")),
            left: parseInt(ssLeft.replace("px","")),
            top: parseInt(ssTop.replace("px","")),
          }
            console.log(RectanglePosition);

            element = null;
            canvas.style.cursor = "not-allowed";
            console.log("finsihed.");
            console.log("Coordinates sent to controller.");
            DrawDone = 1;

              const thumbSize = determineScreenShotSize(RectanglePosition)
              let options = { types: ['screen'], thumbnailSize: thumbSize }

              desktopCapturer.getSources(options, function (error, sources) {
                if (error) return console.log(error)

                sources.forEach(function (source) {
                  if (source.name === 'Entire screen' || source.name === 'Screen 1') {
                    //const screenshotPath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'screenshot.png')
                    const screenshotPath = path.join(__dirname, 'screenshot.png')

                    fs.writeFile(screenshotPath, source.thumbnail.toPng(), function (error) {
                      if (error) return console.log(error)

                      var Jimp = require("jimp");

                      Jimp.read(screenshotPath, function (err, image) {
                          if (err) throw err;
                          console.log(RectanglePosition)
                          image.crop(RectanglePosition.left+2,RectanglePosition.top+2, RectanglePosition.width, RectanglePosition.height )
                          .quality(100)
                          .write("SS.png");

                      });

                      //shell.openExternal('file://' + screenshotPath)
                      shell.openExternal('file://'+path.join(__dirname, 'SS.png'))
                      const message = `Saved screenshot to: ${screenshotPath}`
                      console.log(message);
                    })
                  }
                })
              })


            function determineScreenShotSize (RectanglePosition) {
              console.log(RectanglePosition)
              //const electronScreen = electron.screen
              const screenSize = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workAreaSize
              //const screenSize = electronScreen.getPrimaryDisplay().workArea

              const maxDimension = Math.max(screenSize.width, screenSize.height)
              //const maxDimension = Math.max(x: RectanglePosition.left, y: RectanglePosition.top, width: RectanglePosition.width, height: RectanglePosition.height)
              return {
                width: maxDimension * window.devicePixelRatio,
                height: maxDimension * window.devicePixelRatio
              }
            }



        } else {
          if(DrawDone === 0){
            console.log("begun.");
            mouse.startX = mouse.x;
            mouse.startY = mouse.y;
            element = document.createElement('div');
            element.className = 'rectangle'
            element.style.left = mouse.x + 'px';
            element.style.top = mouse.y + 'px';
            canvas.appendChild(element)
            //canvas.style.cursor = "crosshair";
          } else {
            console.log("drawing is finished. Crop time");
            element = document.createElement('div');
            canvas.appendChild(element)
            canvas.style.cursor = "not-allowed";
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `body { padding:0px; }`

Comment: Nope, this doesnt help

Comment: You have `left:5px` and `top:5px` therefore it will have 5px left and top of your rectangle.

Comment: I undesrstand this, but i have no idea which place is adding this `left:5px` and `top:5px`, because as i said, when i move my cursor to the region where this padding is added, my cursor changes from my custom defined to default, which is strange. Padding should actualy change cusror, to me it looks like Electron window has some king of frame or something..

Comment: Check this out: https://gyazo.com/ee632cc1c307baeb42dbf3a8ee17ea99

Comment: It's added within the html element's property. If you haven't manually added that style to the element it must be added by javascript when the element is modified.

Comment: Add this to your `.rectangle` css to see if it helps `left:inherit !important;top:inherit !important;`

Comment: Now the rectanble is in the corner, but its behavior is strange and it starts drawing right in the top left cornern, cannot draw it in the middle. But the cursor acts the same as before.